# UnsupportedOperationException with MultiPart file upload using Webflux and Spring Boot with Google Cloud Storage

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

When using an alternative `FileSystem` with `FilePart.transferTo` I am seeing an `UnsupportedOperationException` thrown during multipart file upload.

It appears the `SynchronossFilePart` implementation used by Spring switches to a different FileSystemProvider as it is processing the data.  Is there any way to prevent this and force Spring to use only the desired FileSystem?

A snippet is provided below which demonstrates the problem using google-cloud-nio as the Filesystem which tries to persist the uploaded file to google cloud storage.

I am using Spring Boot 2.1.3

```
    @PostMapping(value = "/upload", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
    public Mono<Void> multipartUpload( final @RequestPart("file") FilePart filePart
    ) {

        FileSystem fileSystem = CloudStorageFileSystem.forBucket("my-bucket");

        // Code snippet that demonstrates connectivity to GCP is okay
        //try {
        //    Files.write(fileSystem.getPath("successful-file"), "Just here to prove this works, this data is written to the bucket successfully, can be removed".getBytes());
        //} catch (IOException e) {
        //    e.printStackTrace();
        //}
        return filePart.transferTo(fileSystem.getPath("failed-file"));
    }
```

Relevant Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: null
    at java.base/java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newFileChannel(FileSystemProvider.java:524)
    at java.base/java.nio.channels.FileChannel.open(FileChannel.java:292)
    at java.base/java.nio.channels.FileChannel.open(FileChannel.java:345)
    at org.springframework.http.codec.multipart.SynchronossPartHttpMessageReader$SynchronossFilePart.transferTo(SynchronossPartHttpMessageReader.java:334)
```

Comment: Are you sure "fileSystem.getPath("failed-file")" is not returning NULL?  Given that it is saying "UnsupportedOperationException: null" I suspect there is a value for the IO logic that is not being found.

Comment: That's what I thought initially but it is indeed returning a value, a path equivalent to `gs://my-bucket/failed-file`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CloudStorageFileSystemProvider` extends the java nio class `FileSystemProvider` which is where the exception originates.

`CloudStorageFileSystemProvider` does not override the `newFileChannel` method and the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/spi/FileSystemProvider.html#newFileChannel(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.util.Set,%20java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...)) for the default behaviour of that class states:

> The default provider is required to support the creation of file
>   channels. When not overridden, the default implementation throws
>   UnsupportedOperationException.

This looks like a problem with the google-cloud-nio library, although it's possible the webflux implementation could be improved so as not rely on missing implementations from other providers.

**Update:**
It appears google-cloud-nio has [released](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/pull/4718) an implementation of the newFileChannel method as of version 0.88.0-alpha which should solve this issue